# OKTA logs a successful signin but returns to logon page with error?code=

Tags: okta, okta-signin-widget

Okta noob here and hoping the hive-mind could help.

while I have a successful log int to OKTA according to the logs, it returns to an error page with a url similar to the following

localhost:8080/error?code=Tp59q3-more of the hash-W1EP&state=z8JF0llhhMe-more of the hash-e6iLs1A5Z5

I'm using the sample code here: https://github.com/okta/samples-js-angular/tree/master/okta-hosted-login, which I had previously working. That is, up until the point I added my own custom code to the project.

the things that has me scratching my head is the Login challenge/response dialog for passwords appears as expected, the okta dashboard records a successful login. The redirect URL gives me a hash whereas the help documents don't indicate that is the case.
So not sure if I'm getting a head fake from the error? query string.

The response code I'm receiving is 200.

It doesn't make sense that a dev site would obscure error codes.   so any guidance would be appreciated. Do I need to decode these hashes? Is this a redirect issue?

```
const { CLIENT_ID, ISSUER, OKTA_TESTING_DISABLEHTTPSCHECK } = process.env;

export default {
  oidc: {
    clientId: `${CLIENT_ID}`,
    issuer: `${ISSUER}`,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/callback',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    pkce: true,
    testing: {
      disableHttpsCheck: `${OKTA_TESTING_DISABLEHTTPSCHECK}`
    }
  },
  resourceServer: {
    messagesUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/messages'
  },
};
```

Comment: What are you using for a redirect URI? Hash-bashed routing won't work AFAIK.

Comment: patterned the redirect uri after step 3 in the docs:  https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa-redirect/angular/main/#configure-your-app

Comment: Is there any errors in your browser console? I suspect you might need to add a trusted origin for `http://localhost:8080`.